# How do I set the address of an Outlook internet calendar folder?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to set the address of my Outlook Calendar folder to a specific URL. I can't find any notes on the Internet for this. I would like to set the `newFolder` URL address to a website. This is in Outlook 2010:

```
Folder calendarFolder = this._Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Folder;

NavigationPane pane = this._Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane;
CalendarModule navigation = pane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar) as CalendarModule;

NavigationGroup group = navigation.NavigationGroups.Create("Appleby Calendars");

Folder newFolder = calendarFolder.Folders.Add("Athletics", Type.Missing) as Folder;
group.NavigationFolders.Add(newFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the folder by calling this method in the application object. This will create a new folder and you can move it to any navigation folder that you want.

```
Folder newFolder = this._Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder("<the .ics usl>") as Folder;
```